# How can I undo paragraph addings?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am using iText 7.2.1.

I have multiple long articles of various lengths. What I need to do is:

1. Pick one article in the candidate set and add it into my document. The newly added article will be right following the previous one. There may be automatic page changing.
2. Check if this newly added article meets some criterion. (For example: Check if its ending line is at the right position of a page)
3. If not, undo this adding, and try next article in the candidate set.

There seems no "undo"s for a `Document`. So I'm wondering if I can duplicate my current document to test. Or is there any other way to test before adding?

Comment: Hey, do you think you can share the code you currently have and also share some visual explanation of what you are trying to achieve? You can use the `Document` with `immediateFlush=false` mode which allows you to remove/readd content afterwards and also do `relayout()` calls.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Thanks for your hint about `immediateFlush=false`. But I still can't find in the documentation which method in `Document` can remove things. My code is too long and most of them is off topic. In simple terms, I want to optimize the sequence of multiple articles to minimize ugly layout, like an article ending's very few lines are at the top of a page, or too small space is left for the next article, etc.

Comment: Okay, I see that one way to overcome this you are looking for is duplicating the document. But you can as well maintain a list of "selected" elements, and each time you want to test a new candidate you can create a new document, add all the elements from the currently selected list into the new document and test your new candidate. This approach is not super efficient of course but it should work. Have you tried that? Any problems with it? If you tried it and there are some issues with it then it makes sense to add your code as the baseline to the question

Comment: @AlexeySubach Thanks very much. Readding everything seems reasonable though a little slow. I'll try it.

Comment: Hey @landings, how are things going? Have you been able to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I find that the only reliable way is like your suggestion: To redo an adding, I delete all pages and add all necessary articles back. Very slow but it's the only way. I think it may be faster if I can duplicate / deep clone existing `PdfDocument` or `PdfWriter` so that I can make backups before adding, but I haven't researched on it. Multiple `Document`s from one `PdfDocument` is problematic for me because different paces of page change will produce exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question's comments section the idea of `relayout` was suggested, however, it hasn't been demonstrated how it can be efficiently applied to your case. This is how I see your demands:

1. You want to consider paragraphs one by one. In the rest of the answer I will call these parahraphs "candidates".
2. For each of the candidates you want to layout it and check whether it meets some of your criteria.
3. If the anwer is yes, then you want to add this paragraph to the document.
4. In any case, regardless whether the candidate was added or not, you want to proceed with another candidate.

I want to explicitly mention the word "layout" rather than "add": in the solution proposed below I will try layouting candidates without actually adding them to the document. Once the candidate is layouted, you can check it against your criteria and if it meets them, then the candidate should be added.

Below is the main part of the code. As you can see, here I do the following: until the requested number of paragraphs is added, I generate paragraphs of random size and check with the help of `isParagraphAccepted` whether they are accepted or not. If true, then I add them to the document and reduce the number of paragraphs to be added.

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    RootRenderer rootRenderer = doc.getRenderer();
    Rectangle defaultArea = pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize();
    
    int paragraphsToAddCount = 10;

    LoremIpsum lorem = LoremIpsum.getInstance();
    int minLoremCount = 25;
    int maxLoremCount = 50;

    int counter = 0;
    while (paragraphsToAddCount > 0) {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(lorem.getParagraphs(minLoremCount, maxLoremCount));
        if (isParagraphAccepted(p, rootRenderer, defaultArea)) {
            doc.add(p);
            paragraphsToAddCount--;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("We have considered " + counter + " paragraphs.");
    doc.close();
```

The magic, however, is done in `isParagraphAccepted`, so let's take a look:

```
    boolean isParagraphAccepted(Paragraph p, RootRenderer rootRenderer, Rectangle defaultArea) {
    Rectangle currentArea = null == rootRenderer.getCurrentArea()
            ? defaultArea
            : rootRenderer.getCurrentArea().getBBox();

    IRenderer paragraphRenderer = p.createRendererSubTree().setParent(rootRenderer);
    LayoutResult layoutResult = paragraphRenderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, currentArea)));
    while (LayoutResult.FULL != layoutResult.getStatus()) {
        currentArea = defaultArea;
        paragraphRenderer = layoutResult.getOverflowRenderer();
        layoutResult = paragraphRenderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, currentArea)));
    }

    // checking against some criteria
    return layoutResult.getOccupiedArea().getBBox().getHeight() > 500;
}
```

Basically, in this method the following is done: the pararaph gets layouted page after page until it's finally fully layouted and then I check the area it occupies on the last page against some criteria.

Comment: Thanks! This is genius. Though a little low-level. After careful reading I feel I can understand most of this.